# web server and database server distance

Tags: web-server

I want to seperate my server into two parts: web server and dbserver. My web server is located in Turkey and my dbserver is located in Germany. I cant change my web server because my
agreement is based on my Ip adresses. I want to locate my dbserver in Germany because more cheap then Turkey. But... I have a problem in here. When you call a db action, first, you are going to Turkey for IIS and IIS is going to Germany for Dbserver. It is too far and so slow to response back. Any idea? Is it wrong that the distance is so far between web server and dbserver? Or Are there any solutions for this problem?

Comment: Solution: move it closer.

Comment: Jesus. What's the response/ping time between the two servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move your webserver closer to the database, and leave a proxy in Turkey.  It can be either an HTTP proxy (like squid, varnish, nginx, etc) or a TCP proxy.  In either case, it will look like it's still there.

The advantage is because you will be stretching the HTTP connection, which is meant to cross the world, and keep the DB accesses (which are designed for LANs) local.

Comment: Ok, It seems like usefull, thank you. I will try this.